# How to modify the feed parsing script to parse only in-stock products?

Tags: scripting

There is a script for parsing a trade feed, it pulls the specified parameters into google tables, pulls out all the products that are in the feed.

```
function main() {
getURLs();
pushToSheet();
}
function getURLs() {

var FeedXML = UrlFetchApp.fetch(FeedURL).getContentText(); 

var items = FeedXML.split('<item>');
var len = items.length;

for(var key = 0; key < len; key++){
var url_temp = items[key].split('<g:link>')[1];
   
if (typeof(url_temp) !== "undefined"){
      var url = url_temp.split('</g:link>')[0];
}

var cat_temp = items[key].split('<g:product_type>')[1];

if(cat_temp !== undefined){
  var cat = cat_temp.split('</g:product_type>')[0];
}

if(url !== undefined){
  output.push([url, cat]);
}

}
}

function pushToSheet(){
var sheetURL = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
var sheet2 = sheetURL.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
sheet2.clearContents();
sheet2.appendRow(['URL', 'Custom label']); // Название столбцов в документе
sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, output.length, 
output[0].length).setValues(output); 
}
```

My question is:

1. How to make the script pull only the url and the type of goods that are in stock?

Comment: That's not a scripting question.  It involves application specific information.  Turn it into a scripting question and you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Have you considered using XmlService